# angular http POST call retry based on the response of first POST call

Tags: angular, http, post, httpclient

I have a scenario where I need to retry the post call based on the response flag from the first attempt of the same post call.

I have following service call

```
this.CommonService.postRequest(this.RequestData)
.subscribe((data:Response) => 
{ if(data){ 
//based on the flag in the response data I need to make same call again until the flag is false. 
} });
```

I will get a flag in the response when I make the above call. If I get a flag true then I need to retry same call. I can retry the same call for maximum 3 times.

any idea how to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the **`switchMap`** operator to wait for the response of the first request to arrive before firing the second request.

```
return this.http.get('url/1')
  .switchMap(res1 => {
    // use res1 response
    this.http.get('url/2')
  })
  .subscribe(res2 => {

  })
```

Comment: In my case the the 2nd attempt is for the same http call.

Comment: replace with the same url then

Comment: see my UPDATE below. can you guide me what exactly I need to change

Answer (score 0):

Use rxjs retry or retryWhen:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retry.html

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html